# Spring DI Web-App @Autowired Class is null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm trying to autowire a Repository (backend package) from my Web package, but i get a `NullPointerException`.

I have two packages:

- Backend (applicationContext.xml, Repository, Model)
- Web

**My SRC/MAIN/webapp/WEB-INF/Web.XML:**

```
    <!--Load Spring Config -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-db.xml
        <!--classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml-->
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- The Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext. It is registered to Servlet Container -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <!--   <param-value>Production</param-value> -->
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ApplicationContext.XML

```
<!-- Scan for annotations and register them -->
<context:component-scan base-package="de.haegerconsulting.telculator.*"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Detect @Transactional -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <!-- Define Hibernate JPA Vendor Adapter -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="database" value="H2"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="secondary"/>
</bean>

<!-- Datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem://localhost/~/telculator;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Java Class which should autowire my repository

```
@Autowired
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
```

The View (Upload a .csv file)

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadController {

private UploadedFile file;
private String destination = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

public void upload() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = file.getInputstream();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destination + file.getFileName());

        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        try {
            ImportCsvServiceImpl importCsvService = new ImportCsvServiceImpl(destination + file.getFileName());
            // Write Sets and store them in Database
            importCsvService.readCsvFile();
            **importCsvService.storeEntities(); --> NullPointerException!**
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // File Upload was successful
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Successful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The Unit-Tests work great. 
I get an repository injected and all tests are fine.

Could you please help me?
Am i missing something?

**Update

Stacktrace**

> ```
> INFORMATION: Server startup in 5240 ms java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> ```
>
> de.haegerconsulting.telculator.backend.service.impl.ImportCsvServiceImpl.storeEntities(ImportCsvServiceImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   de.haegerconsulting.telculator.web.Controller.FileUploadController.upload(FileUploadController.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   de.haegerconsulting.telculator.backend.service.impl.ImportCsvServiceImpl.storeEntities(ImportCsvServiceImpl.java:186)
>     at
>   de.haegerconsulting.telculator.web.Controller.FileUploadController.upload(FileUploadController.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   de.haegerconsulting.telculator.backend.service.impl.ImportCsvServiceImpl.storeEntities(ImportCsvServiceImpl.java:194)
>     at
>   de.haegerconsulting.telculator.web.Controller.FileUploadController.upload(FileUploadController.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Show us the full stack trace. The line `importCsvService.storeEntities();` cannot itself throw a `NullPointerException`, something within it does? Why do you have a `@ManagedBean` annotation?

Comment: Stacktrace updated! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
ImportCsvServiceImpl importCsvService = new ImportCsvServiceImpl(destination + file.getFileName());
```

You are creating a Service here manually and not getting it from Spring Container, so this obviously is not Spring managed. Any bean which is autowired using annotation within this Class would also not be injected by Spring unless of course you have explicitly initialized it by asking it from Spring application context  in its constructor or any initializing method which anyway would make use of auto-wiring annotation useless).

Your `fileUploadController` is a JSF managed bean and if `importCsvService` is intended to be Spring Managed then you would need to follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455223/how-to-autowire-into-jsf-managed-beans) to make it work by just autowiring.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got another error and if i debug the code i see an injected object!